# Filling values in rows of column in a data frame, if condition based on 2 other columns row values in the same data frame is met

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am new to python and pandas and have a csv file that am reading into a panda data frame. Find it attached below.

I am trying to populate the the column, OND_ORIGIN and OND_DEST based on row values in the PLDATE.

The logic is for every flight flown on the same day, the OND_ORIGIN and OND_DEST should be the same as for departure_from and Arr_to columns

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv


location = r'C:\Users\bi.reports\Desktop\output.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(location,sep='\s*,\s*',engine='python')
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['COUPON_NUMBER'] == 1:
        df.OND_ORIGIN = df.DEP_FROM 
        #df.OND_DEST = df.DEP_FROM
    elif  row['COUPON_NUMBER'] == 2:
        #df.OND_ORIGIN = df.DEP_FROM 
        df.OND_DEST = df.ARR_TO
    elif row['COUPON_NUMBER'] == 3:
        #df.OND_ORIGIN = df.DEP_FROM 
        df.OND_DEST = df.ARR_TO   
    else:
    df.OND_ORIGIN = df.DEP_FROM  
    #df.OND_DEST = df.ARR_TO 

   df.to_csv('out.csv', sep=',',index = False)
```

[csv file in use](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-YHr391t2TxNDNwZjFRektJTWs)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df['COUPON_NUMBER'] == 1, 'OND_ORIGIN'] = df.DEP_FROM
df.loc[df['COUPON_NUMBER'].isin([2,3]), 'OND_DEST'] = df.ARR_TO
df.loc[~df['COUPON_NUMBER'].isin([1,2,3]), 'OND_ORIGIN'] = df.DEP_FROM
```

or bit optimized:

```
df.loc[df['COUPON_NUMBER'].isin([2,3]), 'OND_DEST'] = df.ARR_TO
df.loc[~df['COUPON_NUMBER'].isin([2,3]), 'OND_ORIGIN'] = df.DEP_FROM
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, however when i run it, for every row only one of the columns get populated. i.e (IF OND_DEST is populated, OND_ORIGIN is blank and viceversa.

Comment: @MTK, you should NOT run it for every row - it's a vectorized solution. Just replace your 'for ... loop' with these two rows...

Comment: I did replace the for loop. If you can have a look at the CSV, I would like to come up with OND_ based on PLDATE column. E.g since coupon 1 and 2 are flown on the same date, the ond_origin should be HRE and OND_Destination KGL for both coupons. and for coupon 3 and 4 the ond_origin KGL and ond_destination HRE for both.

Comment: @MTK, i don't have access to your `C:\Users\bi.reports\Desktop\output.csv`, so i can't have a look at your CSV file... ;)

Comment: it is attached in link shared after the code, titled 'csv in use' or use this link -> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-YHr391t2TxNDNwZjFRektJTWs